# SQL: Create crosswalk for single table with rows that reference multiple, potentially nested, rows

Tags: sql, mariadb, heidisql

I'll start with the table I'm working with (note: I cannot change this table):

```
ID      LN_0    LN_1    LN_2    isParent
4508    14883   14884   0       Y
7164    14128   0       0       Y
7169    9021    0       0       Y
9021    4508    0       0       N
14128   14137   14169   0       Y
14137   0       0       0       N
14169   0       0       0       N
14883   0       0       0       N
14884   0       0       0       N
```

The LN_0-2 columns contain ID #'s for other rows.  What I want to be able to do, is create a crosswalk table with 2 columns, that has every unique combination of parent ID's (ID's where isParent=Y) and ID's that parent ID references in it's row, and, here's the hard part, all of the potential references of references of references etc.

The result for the data above would look like this:

```
ParentID References
4508     4058
4508     14883
4508     14884
7164     7164
7164     14128
7164     14137
7164     14169
7169     9021
7169     4508
7169     14883
7169     14884
14128    14128
14128    14137
14128    14169
```

I'm using HeidiSQL to connect to a MariaDB.

Comment: Why `7169, 4508` appears in the result when the `9021 4508 0 0 N` is marked with `N`?

Comment: It's kind of like strings of beads.  Ugh, this is a terrible way to describe it, but I can't think of a better one right now...

Comment: It's kind of like strings of beads.  Each string has a topmost bead (isParent=Y), and then a number of child beads from 0 to infinity.  7169 is a top bead.  I want to know all of the beads connected to 7169.  7169 goes to 9021, 9021 goes to 4508, which branches into 14883 and 14884, both of which have no children, so that's it for 7169.  7169 then get's matched up with all of it's children, one of which is 4508.